# Target specific localization in swift?

Tags: ios, nslocalizedstring, localizable.strings

I have a project with multiple targets.

Most localizations are shared by all targets.
I have them in `Localizable.strings`.

In addition, each target has strings to localize that occur only in that target.

Is there a preferred way to have an additional target specific `.strings` file?

If so, how can I use `NSLocalizedString` to search localizations 
in `Localizable.strings` and/or the target specific `.strings`?

Technically I could put all localizations for all targets into `Localizable.strings` and deploy the with all targets (No problem, there are no target specific localizations for the same string).

But this would a little messy to maintain.

So is there a way to use a target specific additional `.strings` file?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7712318/ios-iphone-nested-localizable-strings-files/59981016#59981016