# iPhone : Manage localization from server not from bundle

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, localization

Adding strings localization files in iPhone bundle is very simple and perfectly fine but there is only one drawbacks every time we need to upload new build on AppStore when we add new language in app.

Is there any other way like we can manage Localization from server, when we start app we download all label string and Localiza image from server and stored in document directory and run accordingly. Download data according to language...

So can we do like this and the main things Apple can reject that kinds of scenario ?

Comment: If you don't mind, Can i find any good tutorial on this.

Comment: Yes.
Please refer the link.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7946686/adding-strings-localization-files-from-a-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Actually we used that way and there were no issues with Apple.

Answer (score 0):

I confirm no problem with Apple too, just note that you won't be able to override the localizable.strings file. You have to create your own way to store and read the strings. It means if your app is already in development, there will be some effort for an application-wise refactoring.