# Is it possible to access the App Bundle's en.lproj?

Tags: objective-c, ios, localization

I would like to be able to change the language files within the language directories. For example let say I have a japanese language update, then I can have the app grab a localizable.strings file from a FTP site, and then write to the jp.lproj direcotry.

Another example is to have a NEW language uploaded to the app.  My app would again load the localizable.strings file from a FTP site, and then create a ch.lproj directory and put that new language in there.

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: I can see how it would be nice to be able to update localizations without have to do updates. It might violate Apple guidelines though. I mean, I doubt Apple actually has a look at localized text content (maybe they run it by a blacklisted word finding engine though, some companies do this as part of localization checks), but this can end up quite prominently in the app and in theory it could show "forbidden" things such as blasphemy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The entire app bundle is read-only for the app. You can not add or modify files in there.

You could store resources e.g. in "Library/Application Support" and load them from there. You would have to replace e.g. `NSLocalizedString` by  `NSLocalizedStringFromTableInBundle`, or specify your resource bundle in `initWithNibName:bundle:`, so that might get complicated.