# Updating .stringsdict localization files over-the-air

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, localization

I'm looking for a way to update stringsdict localization files over-the-air without having to release a new version in the appStore. So ideally I want my stringdict files on a webserver, and the iOS app should download these files from the website and update the local strings.

After doing some research, I realized that we cannot update files in the bundle it was shipped in however I found some reports saying we could store/load localizations in/from the application support folder.

[source #1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12358044/can-i-load-a-localizable-strings-file-into-an-ios-app-over-the-air?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[source #2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13625008/ios-could-i-change-the-localizable-strings-content-during-runtime)

[source #3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12358379/is-it-possible-to-access-the-app-bundles-en-lproj)

Can this also be applied to stringsdict files because I'm trying but no success so far.

Comment: Did you successfully update localizable strings, before talking about stringdict, to see if the answers in the linked question are good?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically you need to create a `.bundle` with your new strings and make your app download it. After that, I think it's possible to create a `NSBundle` object using your freshly downloaded translations and swizzle a couple of methods from the main `NSBundle` currently used by the system.

I've tried something similar, but found out that it's much easier to integrate an existing service such as [Smartling](http://smartling.com) or [Lokalise](https://lokalise.co). They already have an SDK that allows you to update your translation over the air.

Also I found it's much easier to manage all my translations there.