# Update Localizable.strings file Runtime in iPhone

Tags: objective-c, ios, localization

I want to update or replace Localizable.strings Runtime. i have .strings files on server. so if any one can update .strings files on server. then also i need to update value or replace into bundle.

or

can i read .strings file form server directly? and make all static string localized.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I load a localizable.strings file into an iOS app over-the-air](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12358044/can-i-load-a-localizable-strings-file-into-an-ios-app-over-the-air)

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can. You have to roll your own.

If you look at the NSLocalizableString macro, you can make your own like :

RMLocalizableString that instead of pointing to the resources, points to a file you have downloaded in your documentation folder. But of course you have to make sure the file is actually there.

Comment: do you have any example for that?

Comment: @RomitMewada: Take a look at the definition of `NSLocalizableString()`, it's self-documenting.

Comment: #define NSLocalizedString(key, comment) \
     [[NSBundle mainBundle] localizedStringForKey:(key) value:@"" table:nil]

Comment: But of course you can just make this into your own method, from database or whatever you think of

Comment: But you can't use NSLocalizedString unless the file is called Localizable.string and is included in your product at compile time

Comment: no i don't wants to inculde Localizable.strings file into my project. read out side from project.

Comment: Yes you need to roll your own, as I explained